# Is it possible to determine if a variable is an activerecord object or not?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to make a super generic class that when inherited from I can call a generic Sidekiq worker.

The idea would be to have all my services able to be called either normally or asynchronously. The problem is I would like to pass objects to the service but I can only pass pointers to the worker.

So if my service needs a `User` and a `String` I would currently have:

```
*args = [#<User:y6t4ert56uu6>, "I'm a string"]
```

For this to work I will need to make this array:

```
[{activerecord: true, class: "User", value: user_id}, {activerecord: false, class: "String", value: "I'm a string"}]
```

Once I know `User` is an activerecord object I can safely assume there's an `id` (presuming I'm only passing saved objects). Otherwise I would just output the value of the variable.

An idea of the perfect solution would be: (without the important code)

```
user = User.first
str = "Hello"

is_activerecord(user) # returns true
is_activerecord(str) # returns false
```

Can anyone suggest ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for `some_object.class < ActiveRecord::Base`? [`Module#<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-3C) if you only care that there is an `id` then why not just `some_object.respond_to?(:id)`

Comment: Oh cool, I wondered if I could save navigate `.id`, but assumed it wasn't possible. Thanks for that!

Comment: safe navigate* :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Object.is_a?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) to the rescue:

```
user = User.first
str = "Hello"

user.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Base) # true
str.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Base)  # false
```

Comment: Awesome! I knew there was a simple solution. Thanks for answering

Comment: By the way, this will *not* (as the OP asked) "determine if a **variable** is an activerecord object or not" (**bold** emphasis mine), it will instead determine if the **object** that is **referenced** by the variable is an activerecord object or not. A variable will *never* be an activerecord object. A variable will always be a variable. In fact, variables aren't really "things" in the Ruby language at runtime that you can manipulate. They are very restricted in what you can do: assign, dererefence, that's it. In particular, they are not objects.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Have you already opened a ticket to rename `is_a?` method to `is_a_reference_to_an_object_of?` in `Object` class?

Comment: Why would I do that? It makes no sense. The `Object#is_a?` method tests whether an object is an instance of a module. It does not test whether an object is a reference to an object. In fact, only variables can be references to an object, and variables aren't objects, so clearly such a method cannot possibly exist.